# Remove devices from 2FA of Google sign in

Tags: privacy, security, google

I have 7 devices (mostly tablets and smartphones) where I am logged in with  my Google account. However, 4 of those devices I usually take to shows/concerts and I am afraid of someone stealing them or I losing them (I cant set password/pin on them for several reasons).

The problem is this: when I try to sign in another new device, Google usually sends a 2FA authorization message to all 7 devices. I dont want Google to send authorization requests to those 4 devices that can be stolen. I dont care if the thief will access my files, photos... in the stolen tablets, HOWEVER I dont want the thief to see the authorization messages (2FA).

TLDR: I would like to be signed in on 7 devices but I want 4 of those devices to not be "trusted" to allow/deny new sign in on other devices.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is only a problem if you lose both a good and a bad device simultaneously to the same person.  The chances are very small.

You can't stop the Google 2fa, it is annoying and silly for other reasons as well.  Google tells you here that you have to log off them !

[image]

If those devices are not to be trusted then perhaps you shouldnt use your normal Google account on them.  I use a different account.